# Clear the event loop before closing node js server

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a node js server with NestJS framework and I have some image processing involved.
The workflow is like it follows: 
req -> image processing (~30s) -> res

What I want to achive is the following. When the server stops (by CTR+C or PM2) I want to block the server from getting any new requests  and to finish all the processes from event loop (the image processing and other current requests) and after to close the application.

Is this achievable

Comment: `When the server stops (by CTR+C or PM2) I want to block the server from getting any new requests` if the server is stopped how it will get new request???

Comment: Just close incoming event sources (sockets, timers etc). The process will self-terminate when there's no more events pending

Comment: @slebetman - they don't.... if i stop my server while the request is still pending then I will receive ERR_CONNECTION_RESET as response. I want to wait untill all the requests are resolved and a response is returned

Comment: @Subburaj - if i press CRL+C I don't wait to stop the server immediately, I want to w8 untiill all the requests are resolved and a response is send but in the same time I don't want to get new requests.

Comment: Don't close active sockets. Just close the listening socket. Call the `.close()` method on the server object (see: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback). The close method only stops listening to new connections without closing currently open connections

Comment: If you're using something like Express or Connect then you can get the server object as the return value from `app.listen()`. You can call `close()` on that which will not terminate currently open connections

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graceful shutdown feature in PM2 .

Refer : https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/signals-clean-restart/

Comment: And how does it help? How can I wait untill the event loop has finished?